# Two submit buttons, one form (Yii)

Tags: php, forms, button, yii

I have two CHtml::submitButton() in my form, namely "Accept" and "Reject". Each of the buttons has a specific ID ... When any of the two are pressed, i would like to trigger an action in my controller. Below are the code snippets.

=========================================================

**View**

```
<?php
echo CHtml::beginForm('mycontrollerName/AcceptUserRegistration','get');
?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Accept', array('id' => 'accept')); ?>
<? echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; ?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Reject', array('id' => 'reject')); ?> 
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

========================================================

**Controller**

```
public function actionAcceptUserRegistration() {

$value = $_GET['id'];

if($value == "accept"){
//will do something here
}

if($value == "reject"){
//will do something here.
}

}
```

======================================================================

When i implement it this way. the get value in the controller side is empty. What I'm I doing wrong? Or is there any other way around this?

Comment: Please post your HTML code instead of the PHP code that generates it.

Comment: Why don't you try $_REQUEST in place of $_GET?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to give the submit button a name (unless your framework does some magic which we cannot know about - you should really post the generated HTML code!).

If you do so, the value in `$_GET['buttonname']` will be its *value* (not its id), i.e. `Accept` or `Reject`. This becomes pretty messy as soon as you get into i18n, so you might want to use different *names* for the buttons and then check `isset($_GET['buttonname1'])` and `isset($_GET['buttonname2'])`

Comment: Thanks ThiefMaster for your quick response.

Comment: so should I do something like this <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Accept', array('id' => 'accept', 'name' => accept)); ?>

Comment: Ok... and in the $_GET[], should it be $_GET['Accept'] or $_GET['accept']..?

Comment: `print_r($_GET);` would be a good thing for you to do... The key in that array is the field name, so it's lowercase `accept`/`reject`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code example for what you are trying to achive:

VIEW:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::beginForm('mycontrollerName/AcceptUserRegistration','get');
?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Accept', array('id' => 'accept', 'name' => 'accept')); ?>
<? echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; ?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Reject', array('id' => 'reject', 'name' => 'reject')); ?> 
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Note: I added the name parameter. As name is not displayed to the user, you can use accept instead of Accept.

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actionAcceptUserRegistration() {

if(isset($_GET['accept'])) {
     //accepted
} else if(isset($_GET['reject'])) {
     //rejected
}
//I recommend using POST method instead of GET for posting the form.
}
```